# Raphael Svg Elements: No event handlers working

Tags: javascript, jquery, user-interface, mouseevent, raphael

In the jsfiddle, when I click the blue rectangle,generated via Raphaeljs, I want an event handler to fire.  Please see my attempts at the bottom of the fiddle code.  Following are what I attempted to set mouse handling for the rectangle.

I have tried via jquery:

```
$(object).on("click", function(){})
```

and via Raphaeljs built in handler methods:

```
raphaelObject.click(function(){})
```

Please see this jfiddle where I load 1 rectangle* and try both above methods to change  the contents of the div with `id= "debug"`when you click the blue rectangle:  http://jsfiddle.net/dhcjLt7q/1/ **Before you look at the jsfiddle, PLEASE READ THE NOTES**

several notes about the jsfiddle:

1. **scroll down to the bottom to see the event handlers**
2. first ~2000 (or first line if you did not press tidyup) lines are autogenerated from somewhere else, I just copy pasted the results there and they are NOT significant or of interest as related to the question.  But they are necessary for the fiddle to work.
3. the entire `addNodeToPaper` block is on line ~139
4. I'm sorry in general, first javascript project.

Comment: What are you trying to do? can you please be more clear? that's way to much code for "dynamically generated elements with or without events"

Comment: The overarching goal is to manage the placement (set via `spider.init()` and `spider.buildSpider() ), text content, and animations (which currently will be `spider.settle()` to return nodes to default positions and hide subcontent nodes, `spider.select`). I cannot get any event handlers to work on the raphael/svg elements.

Only the methods called by ones mentioned above are of interest.

Comment: But for the context of the question, I want event handlers to work for the rectangle that appears in the fiddle.  Example handlers that I thought would work on the rectangle are at the very bottom of the code.  IGNORE FIRST 2000 LINES.

Comment: @crockz see the question now.  Hopefully more clear.

Comment: Can you update your question and explain what's your objective, it would be much easier, the code is still a mess and I just see a blue rectangle, what you mean with dynamically? from a form or it's drawn by the server?

Comment: Updated.  My objective is that when I click the blue rectangle, I'd like the debug div to change.  That is the only issue I am having.

Everything else works as expected.  I included the other pieces of code in the event that the issue is somewhere unexpected.

Comment: Remove all of the other unnecessary code _unless_ it causes the problem. Then add it back in bit by bit if it does. If it isn't remove it all and repost.